# Aggregate and visualize entries in SQLite Database by Timestamp entries

Tags: php, javascript, sql, sqlite, d3.js

I have a big SQLite - Database that contains entries like this:

```
rowID   timestamp    employee  sold         
1       1345294648   myer      1
2       1351508109   miller    2          
3       1351508109   smith     8
4       1351508109   miller    10
5       1351508109   smith     1
6       1353243448   myer      10
```

It represents the amount of units certain employees have sold at a certain time.

With the following code in php i can get the sold units per employee:

```
<?php

$response = array();
$db = new PDO("sqlite:./db.sqlite");

$query_count = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM myTable GROUP BY employee");

while ($row = $query_count -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$current_employee = $row['employee'];

$response[$current_employee]["sold"] = $row['sold'];

}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

This will give back the following JSON - formatted data:

```
{ 
  "miller" : { "sold" : 12 },
  "myer" : { "sold" : 11 },
  "smith" : { "sold" : 9 }
}
```

Now i want to separate the sales to the distinct months, like this:

```
{
   "miller":{
      "sold":{
         "january":1,
         "february":8,
         "march":9
      }
   },
   "myer":{
      "sold":{
         "january":10,
         "february":11,
         "march":13
      }
   },
   "smith":{
      "sold":{
         "january":11,
         "february":10,
         "march":10
      }
   }
}
```

After that, i want to visualize the data with an bar chart, like this but non-stacked:

http://bl.ocks.org/1134768

Is there a SQL - Request / PHP-Script that can help me?

I'm glad for every answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: Read up on date handling in sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite delivers different date functions, to aggregate data by dates:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html